# Writing to file in R one line after the other

Tags: r

I have the following piece of code to write to an R file one line at a time.

```
for (i in c(1:10)){
  writeLines(as.character(i),file("output.csv"))

}
```

It just writes 10 presumably over-writing the previous lines. How do I make R append the new line to the existing output? append = TRUE does not work.

Comment: Can you not just remove the for loop and pass a vector of text to writelines?

Comment: The text is dynamically generated in each loop in the actual code. This is just an example.

Comment: Then let the for loop generate the vector, and pass that vector to writeLines()?

Comment: In my actual code, there is a data frame generated in each loop. I want to write that data frame on a new line to the output file. So I am specifically looking for code that in each loop writes some output to a new line in an output file.

Comment: I tried your idea but then R writes everything to one line.

Comment: even when adding the sep="\n" argument from nurandi's answer?

Comment: @Jarn Schober sep="\n" could work. I did not try that. But I found a workaround for my issue..So I don't need the code any more. But thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append = TRUE` **does** work when using the function `cat` (instead of `writeLines`), but only if you give `cat` a *file name*, not when you give it a `file` object: whether a file is being appended to or overwritten is a property of the file object itself, i.e. it needs to be specifried *when the file is being opened*.

Thus both of these work:

```
f = file('filename', open = 'a') # open in “a”ppend mode
for (i in 1 : 10) writeLines(i, f)
```

```
for (i in 1 : 10) cat(i, '\n', file = 'filename', sep = '', append = TRUE)
```

Calling `file` manually is almost never necessary in R.

… but as the other answer shows, you can (and should!) avoid the loop anyway.

Comment: I get this in R.  for (i in c(1:10)){
+   writeLines(as.character(i),"output.csv",append=TRUE)
+   
+ }
Error in writeLines(as.character(i), "output.csv", append = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (append = TRUE)
>   In the actual code the text to be written to the file is dynamically generated in each loop. What I showed is an example.

Comment: @user2371765 Ah right, `append` is an argument for `cat`, but not for `writeLines`. Fixed.

Comment: How do you close the file? I am not being allowed to delete 'filename'.

Comment: @user2371765 When passing a filename string to functions such as `cat` and `writeLines`, they will close the file themselves automatically. When opening the file via `file`, you can call `close` to close it.

Comment: I get "argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'" when I try to write a certain object to the file. In my actual code, it is not a number but a data frame. Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: @user2371765 `cat` only handles strings (and primitive vectors of length 1 which it converts to strings). If you want to save tables in files, use the appropriate functions (e.g. `write.csv`, or the corresponding function from the ‘readr’ package).

Comment: Thank you. Can you modify your response to use write.csv instead of cat? Please assume i is a data frame, and that I want to write each data frame on a new line? In my code, I put everything in a list and then used write.csv to write that list to a file. But that does not allow me to write each data frame to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a loop. Use newline escape charater `\n` as separator instead.

```
vec <- c(1:10)
writeLines(as.character(vec), file("output.csv"), sep="\n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In the actual code, the text to be written to the file is dynamically generated in each loop.